# Why am i getting this error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException?

Tags: lucene, noclassdeffounderror

Why am i getting this error message?

```
Testcase: createIndexBatch_usingTheTestArchive(src.LireHandlerTest):        Caused an ERROR
at/lux/imageanalysis/ColorLayoutImpl
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: at/lux/imageanalysis/ColorLayoutImpl
        at net.semanticmetadata.lire.impl.SimpleDocumentBuilder.createDocument(Unknown Source)
        at net.semanticmetadata.lire.AbstractDocumentBuilder.createDocument(Unknown Source)
        at backend.storage.LireHandler.createIndexBatch(LireHandler.java:49)
        at backend.storage.LireHandler.createIndexBatch(LireHandler.java:57)
        at src.LireHandlerTest.createIndexBatch_usingTheTestArchive(LireHandlerTest.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: at.lux.imageanalysis.ColorLayoutImpl
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
```

I am trying to create a Lucene index using documents that are created using Lire. When i am getting to the point where it tries to create a document using the document builder it gives me this error message.

input paramaters first run: 
filepath: "test_archive" (this is a image archive)
whereToStoreIndex: "test_index" (Where i am going to store the index)
createNewIndex: true

Since the method is recursive (see the if statement where it checks if is a directory) it will call itself multiple times but all the recursive calls uses createNewIndex = false.

Here is the code:

```
public static boolean createIndexBatch(String filepath, String whereToStoreIndex, boolean createNewIndex){
        DocumentBuilder docBldr = DocumentBuilderFactory.getDefaultDocumentBuilder();
        try{
            IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(
                                                    FSDirectory.open(new File(whereToStoreIndex)),
                                                    new SimpleAnalyzer(),
                                                    createNewIndex,
                                                    IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED
                                                    );
            File[] files = FileHandler.getFilesFromDirectory(filepath);
            for(File f:files){
                if(f.isFile()){
                    //Hopper over Thumbs.db filene...
                    if(!f.getName().equals("Thumbs.db")){
                        //Creating the document that is going to be stored in the index
                        String name = f.getName();
                        String path = f.getPath();
                        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(f);
                        Document doc = docBldr.createDocument(stream, f.getName());

                        //Add document to the index
                        indexWriter.addDocument(doc);
                    }
                }else if(f.isDirectory()){
                    indexWriter.optimize();
                    indexWriter.close();
                    LireHandler.createIndexBatch(f.getPath(), whereToStoreIndex, false);
                }
            }
            indexWriter.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.print("IOException in createIndexBatch:\n"+e.getMessage()+"\n");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are missing a java library.

I think you need to download Caliph & Emir, that may be used indirectly by Lire.

http://www.semanticmetadata.net/download/

Comment: Thank you! worked! I was missing a jar library called caliph-emir-cbir.jar. I only had the lucene and lire library.

Comment: Getting same error, but dont which files need to download, I have tries much didn't get success.